# Check if a variable is null in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to check if a variable is null.  If it is null, then I want to set a value to that variable:

```
//data type of var is  number 
if Var = null then
  var :=5;
endif
```

But I am geting error in it.  How can I check if a variable is null?

I am using oracle data type

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
if var is NULL then
  var :=5;
end if;
```

Answer (score 28):

Use:

```
IF Var IS NULL THEN
  var := 5;
END IF;
```

Oracle 9i+:

```
var := COALESCE(Var, 5)
```

Other alternatives:

```
var := NVL(var, 5)
```

Reference:

- [COALESCE](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/coalesce.php)
- [NVL](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php)
- [NVL2](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl2.php)

Answer (score 20):

In PL/SQL you can't use operators such as '=' or '<>' to test for `NULL` because all comparisons to `NULL` return `NULL`.  To compare something against `NULL` you need to use the special operators `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` which are there for precisely this purpose.  Thus, instead of writing

```
IF var = NULL THEN...
```

you should write

```
IF VAR IS NULL THEN...
```

In the case you've given you also have the option of using the `NVL` built-in function.  `NVL` takes two arguments, the first being a variable and the second being a value (constant or computed).  `NVL` looks at its first argument and, if it finds that the first argument is `NULL`, returns the second argument.  If the first argument to `NVL` is not `NULL`, the first argument is returned.  So you could rewrite

```
IF var IS NULL THEN
  var := 5;
END IF;
```

as

```
var := NVL(var, 5);
```

I hope this helps.

### EDIT

And because it's nearly ten years since I wrote this answer, let's celebrate by expanding it just a bit.

The `COALESCE` function is the ANSI equivalent of Oracle's `NVL`. It differs from `NVL` in a couple of IMO good ways:

1. It takes any number of arguments, and returns the first one which is not NULL. If all the arguments passed to `COALESCE` are NULL, it returns NULL.
2. In contrast to `NVL`, `COALESCE` only evaluates arguments if it must, while `NVL` evaluates both of its arguments and then determines if the first one is NULL, etc. So `COALESCE` can be more efficient, because it doesn't spend time evaluating things which won't be used (and which can potentially cause unwanted side effects), but it also means that `COALESCE` is not a 100% straightforward drop-in replacement for `NVL`.

Answer (score 4):

Use IS NULL

[reference page](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/isnull.php)

Answer (score 3):

There's also the NVL function

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php

Answer (score 2):

use if var is null

Answer (score 2):

Always remember to be careful with nulls in pl/sql conditional clauses as null is never greater, smaller, equal or unequal to anything. Best way to avoid them is to use nvl.

For example

```
declare
  i integer;
begin
  if i <> 1 then
    i:=1;
    foobar();
  end if;
end;
/
```

Never goes inside the if clause.

These would work.

```
if 1<>nvl(i,1) then
if i<> 1 or i is null then
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
var := coalesce (var, 5);
```

COALESCE is the ANSI equivalent (more or less) of Oracle's NVL function.