# How to check column value is null or not in plsql?

Tags: java, sql, plsql

I have a table with name `Shipment` which has columns `HAWB, MAWB`. How can I check that these two columns are having null value or not ?.

Comment: @ mahendraliya -i have done that...it's not neccessary that every time you find relevant answer..

Comment: I understand :-) please do so when you find an answer relevant and helpful.. Cheers!

Comment: How come this is tagged 'Java'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a variable is null in plsql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984141/check-if-a-variable-is-null-in-plsql)

Answer (score 6):

To find the rows where `HAWB` is null:

```
SELECT * FROM Shipment WHERE HAWB IS NULL;
```

To find the rows where `MAWB` is null:

```
SELECT * FROM Shipment WHERE MAWB IS NULL;
```

If you want to find the rows where `HAWB` isn't null:

```
SELECT * FROM Shipment WHERE HAWB IS NOT NULL;
```

And finally, if you want to find the rows where `MAWB` isn't null:

```
SELECT * FROM Shipment WHERE MAWB IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: how to save this value in some variable if i have to use it on somewhere else in same sql file?

Comment: @Vivek: I'm not sure what exactly you're asking here. Please start a new question for this.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `HAWB is null and MAWB is null` or `is not null` for reverse.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL you can check the values of a column are `null` or not by using `IS NULL` keyword.

To check if the value is `NOT NULL` you can use the keywords `IS NOT NULL`

Eg:

```
Select * from tableName where columnName IS NULL
Select * from tableName where columnName IS NOT NULL
```

Alternatively in Java, you can get the value of this column and check for its value appropriately.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how to save this value in some variable if i have to use it on somewhere else in same sql file?

Comment: You can do it like `Select varName=columnName from tableName Where columnName IS NOT NULL` You have to declare `varName` of the same type as that of the `columnName`.. Hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn pl/sql, you can start [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/toc.htm).

Happy coding!

BTW, that same link has the answer to your [question](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/fundamentals.htm#sthref494) (and more)

Answer (score 0):

Create a code block and create a cursor this will hold the data you need.

Declare

Cursor MyCursor IS

SELECT HAWB, MAWB
   FROM Shipment 
   WHERE ......... (you can select multiple rows or a single row it depends on what you put in the where clause)

BEGIN

For eachRecord IN MyCursor LOOP

```
--You can do any kind of processing in here
-- access the data in the cursor using eachRecord.HAWB OR eachRecord.MAWB 

--This will print all the values stored in the column HAWB if there is only one record then only one value will be printed

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(eachRecord.HAWB);

--same happens here
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(eachRecord.MAWB);
```

--**************************************************

--check if the first value of HAWB or MAWB IS NULL

IF eachRecord.HAWB IS NULL THEN

--Do your processing here

ELSIF  eachRecord.MAWB IS NULL THEN

--Do your processing here

END IF;

LOOP;

END;

The data will remain in the cursor kinda like an array and you can do whatever you want with it in the code block. You can also look at FETCHING the data from the cursor instead of using a LOOP to process it